# Main Menu for 2d game in ALLEGRO5

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, menu, allegro, game-loop

I've big problem with my university project.
I tried to make simple game in Allegro5, but I've stopped at making Main Menu.
I've basic code, but on 4 possibility: Start Game, Options, Credits,Exit. I can see just one of them ( exit ). Don't know how to fix it, can you help me ?

```
    ///////////// MENU
string menu[4] = { "Start Game", "Options", "Credits", "Exit" };

while (!quit)
{
    ALLEGRO_EVENT ev;
    al_wait_for_event(event_queue, &ev);

    if (ev.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_TIMER)
    {
        redraw = true;
    }
    if (ev.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_KEY_DOWN)
    {
        switch (ev.keyboard.keycode)
        {
        case ALLEGRO_KEY_UP:
            checked--;
            break;

        case ALLEGRO_KEY_DOWN:
            checked++;
            break;
        case ALLEGRO_KEY_ESCAPE:
            quit = true;
            break;
        case ALLEGRO_KEY_ENTER:
            active = true;
            break;

        }
    }
    if (checked < 0) //JAK NAM WYJEDZIE PONIZEJ ZERA TO USTAWIAMY NA 3 (ZAPETLA SIE MENU, JAKBYS CHCIAL ZABLOKOWAC TO DAJ NA 0)
    {
        checked = 3;
    }
    if (checked > 3)
    {
        checked = 0;
    }
    else if (ev.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_DISPLAY_CLOSE)
    {
        break;
    }

    **if (redraw && al_is_event_queue_empty(event_queue)) // JEZELI NIE WYKRYWA ZADNEGO RUCHU TO
    {
        redraw = false; // PRZERYSOWANIE WYNOSI 0
        al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(0, 0, 0));
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            int color;
            if (i == checked)
            {
                color = 255;
            }
            else
            {
                color = 11;
            }
            al_draw_bitmap(mmenu, 0, 0, NULL);
            al_draw_text(font, al_map_rgb(123, color, 45), 50, i * 60, NULL, menu[i].c_str()); // I PISZEMY TEKST
        }
    }
    /*else if () // JEDNAK JAK ZOSTANIE WYKRYTY RUCH TO
    {
        redraw = true; // NASTĘPUJE PRZERYSOWANIE BITMAPY ZE ZMIENIONA OPCJA MENU
    }*/**

    al_flip_display();
}


al_destroy_display(display);
al_destroy_timer(timer);
al_destroy_bitmap(mmenu);
al_destroy_event_queue(event_queue);

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Does `al_draw_bitmap(mmenu, 0, 0, NULL);` draw a picture the full size of the screen? It may well be drawing over your text on each iteration.

Comment: I get tip from my friend, try to load everytime bitmap when you change choice in menu. Really ? i don't know how. I tried use for-loop but it doesn't work :(

Comment: http://zapodaj.net/41697daf7c2ca.jpg.html

Comment: So, yes. The `for` loop is correct, but you only need to draw the menu text, *not* the image. Move the image drawing outside of the loop, then draw the text over the top within the loop.